# find files that do not contain a string but after decrypting it

Tags: shell, unix, awk, grep, find

I have lots of encrypted config file with extension .crp on my Linux box. The .crp files can be de-crypted via a tool say dec_crp.

My task is to search if a particular string does not exists in .crp file and list it. Hence as such first I need to de-crypted it - now this tool actually dumps the de-crypted data on standard output console without file name being listed.

```
dec_crp < a.crp
..........
..........
```

Now from the data as printed in standard console I need to verify existence of a string. If the same is not there I need to list that file.

Is there a single line command that acn be used to ahive that?

Answer (score 0):

This will echo the file name (with no other output) if the file does not contain `mystring` after decryption:

```
if ! dec_crp < a.crp | grep -q mystring
then
  echo a.crp
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Or more concisely:

```
dec_crp < a.crp | grep -q mystring || echo a.crp
```

For many:

```
find * -name '*.crp' -printf "dec_crp < '%p' | grep -q mystring || echo '%p'" | sh
```